# reading and displaying a webservice output in classic asp

Tags: web-services, vbscript, asp-classic

I am reading a webservice output from classic asp.

Web service output is as follows.

```html
<boolean xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">true</boolean>
```

This is proper output as expected.

I have written below code to read this output in classic asp.

```
Set obj1 = Server.createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
URL1 = "http://webserive.asmx/method?para=2"
obj1.open "GET", URL1, False
obj1.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
obj1.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", URL1
obj1.send 

if obj1.responseText <> "" Then
    response.write "ok." & obj1.responseText
end if
```

But this output prints following output:

> "ok. true"

There is a space in the output which is not expected.

This is the problem.

Please advice.

Comment: Are you sure that is the output?, try `Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(obj1.ResponseText)` and see what you get then. You will probably end up with `ok.<boolean xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">true</boolean>` the reason you didn't see it before was because it was being rendered as HTML by the browser, by using `Server.HTMLEncode()` the `ResponseText` is encoded so it renders as text on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I may have miss understood what you require. If you want to parse the XML to remove it so only the content of;

```xml
<boolean xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">true</boolean>
```

is returned to the browser in this case `true` then you need to parse the XML using something like XPath to get the underlying value.

```vb
'After the initial Send()

Dim xml, root
If obj1.Status = 200 Then
  Set xml = obj1.ResponseXML
  Call xml.SetProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")
  Set root = xml.DocumentElement
  Call Response.Write(root.SelectSingleNode("boolean").Text)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output from `ResponseText` for all intense and purpose is valid HTML structure as far as an Internet Browser is concerned and will treat it accordingly. When you use `Response.Write()` to send content to a Browser it is sent "as is" so in this case the `<boolean>` element is seen as HTML so only the contained text `true` is outputted.

To fix this you first need to HTML encode the `ResponseText` before you send it to the Browser so the Browser knows to treat what is sent as plain old text. You do this by calling the method `Server.HTMLEncode()`

```vb
Response.Write "ok." & Server.HTMLEncode(obj1.ResponseText)
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx);

> The HTMLEncode method applies HTML encoding to a specified string. This is useful as a quick method of encoding form data and other client request data before using it in your Web application. Encoding data converts potentially unsafe characters to their HTML-encoded equivalent.
>   If the string to be encoded is not Double-Byte Character Set (DBCS), HTMLEncode converts characters as follows:
>
> - The less-than character (`<`) is converted to `&lt;`.
> - The greater-than character (`>`) is converted to `&gt;`.
> - The ampersand character (`&`) is converted to `&amp;`.
> - The double-quote character (`"`) is converted to `&quot;`.
> - Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to `0x80` is converted to `&#<number>`, where `<number>` is the ASCII character value.
>
> If the string to be encoded is DBCS, HTMLEncode converts characters as follows:
>
> - All extended characters are converted.
> - Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to `0x80` is converted to `&#<number>`, where `<number>` is the ASCII character value.
> - Half-width Katakana characters in the Japanese code page are not converted.

At the moment when send the `ResponseText` this happens;

ResponseText

```
<boolean xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">true</boolean>
```

Output at client

```
ok.true
```

If you use `Server.HTMLEncode()` it will be;

ResponseText *(HTML Encoded)*

```
&lt;boolean xmlns=&quote;http://somewebsite.com/&quote;&gt;true&lt;/boolean&gt;
```

Output at client

```
ok.<boolean xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">true</boolean>
```

Comment: At the moment, even if I sent response from webservice as "<string xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">true</string>" or "<string xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">1</string>"

The output displayed is "ok. true" and "ok. 1" respectively.

Everytime the space is added before the responsetext.

Without using server.htmlencode will display as follows. "ok. true"
And with server.htmlencode will display as "ok.<string xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/">true</string>"

Comment: @student You don't need to change any data just make sure you HTML encode before you send it to the browser as any `<anything>` will be treated as HTML. Using `Server.HTMLEncode()` will fix the problem. Is the problem you just don't want the space? If that is the case then you need to parse the `ResponseText` and only send back the `true` or `1` value.