# Read an ASP-Classic file , but display the results line by line in text format instead of rendering the results first

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

My question involves reading ASP files, but instead of rendering them in ASP or HTML.  I need them to be in Text format when it displays the results to the screen.  What I mean is that all of the HTML tags such as `<html>` and `<script>`, are rendered instead of displayed.  So instead of printing the words `<style>` to the screen , it executes the  command, which is the opposite of what I want to happen, if possible.

Further complicating things, after I solve that, I run into a problem I faced before where its difficult to do the same thing with the <% and %> tags for the ASP blocks, which is obviously just runs the blocks when I need it to display the results instead.

Summary - I am trying to get the pure text from the asp file as if it was just a text file instead of executing the ASP classic segments.  Then I need to run each line through either a replace or regex system to then put the rendering back into place with my own CSS markups, think of a homebrew IDE type system that marks the lines when I specify certain display elements to trigger when found.  I want to put custom labels for CSS styling so when I display each line i marks them up with colors and styling so it visually makes more sense on screen for example making  be dark blue on the screen when it reads that line.  I hope that makes sense, I will provide any code you want to see.

Edit - the Summary was to just give you scope, the main question is just how to pull the textstream in as text without executing the html or asp classic code when displaying that text to the screen.  Is it maybe even something that mixing some javascript with might be a good method?  I just had figured there might be a pure ASP Classic way to do this with how it can deal with reading files and such.

```
IF VALIDATED_PAGE <> "" THEN                                                                    

set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")                                            'Create a File Object to access files
set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")                                         'Create a File Object to access files
fs.CopyFile ASP_FILE_LOCATION,EDT_FILE_FORMAT_LOCATION
'Copy the ASP file we want to edit into a .EDT extension
set txt = fso.OpenTextFile(EDT_FILE_FORMAT_LOCATION)                                            'Set the Text from  to use this EDIT File 
LINECOUNT = 0                                                                                       'Set this to ZERO to do manual line number tracking must start at zero

do while txt.AtEndOfStream = false                                                                  'Do these thing while the text file is NOT End Of Stream (END)
    LINECOUNT = LINECOUNT + 1                                                                       'Increase the Line Count number as we go through the file
    Response.Write("<LABEL class='LINENUMBER'>LINE#" & LINECOUNT & "</label>")                      'Mark and display the line numbers  

    IF NOT txt.AtEndOfStream THEN 
        IF InStr(txt.Readline,"div_a1") >= 1 then 
            response.write "A1FOUND"
            NEWLINE = Replace(txt.Readline,"div_a1",("<label style='color:blue;'>" & txt.Readline & "</label>"))
            RESPONSE.WRITE NEWLINE
            DIV_A1 = 1
        END IF
    END IF
    

    IF NOT txt.AtEndOfStream = TRUE THEN Response.Write(txt.ReadLine & "<br>")                                                      'Write the current line to the screen
         
LOOP 
END IF
```

1. LINE#1
2. LINE#2
3. LINE#3
4. LINE#4
5. LINE#5
6. LINE#6 div.css_grid{
7. LINE#7 text-shadow:2px 2px black;
8. LINE#8 margin:0px;
9. LINE#9}

See how the first few lines don't have any information to display as they were html header code and the  tag for line 5, but line 6 after running the `<style>` command then displays the text after it until it hits line 10 for the `</style>`.  Maybe this helps you see more what I am talking about.

Comment: Just treat the ASP file like any other text file, I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read from a text file using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854975/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-using-vbscript)

Comment: You would think so user, but it executes the line instead of write it to screen.  I will check that 2nd comment links out shortly.

Comment: Updated question to include some code blocks to assist.

Comment: That makes no sense unless you are accessing the ASP file via its URL instead of physical file location as that will trigger the ISAPI extension to process the server-side logic. What path are you passing, what is `ASP_FILE_LOCATION` and `EDT_FILE_FORMAT_LOCATION`?

Comment: The VARS are Physical path locations (ie "F:\script\script.asp"), do not worry.  The EDT file location is just a way to copy the .asp to another extension to see if that keeps it from executing the text instead of displaying it.

Comment: So you are telling me that your Classic ASP is being executed when you open it from a file path? I'm not sure how that is even possible as the ISAPI extension runs inside IIS? You're going to have to break down your environment and explain how you have come to this conclusion.

Comment: Well nothing special was changed for ISAPI but it could be some other css code perhaps.  I stripped the code down to basics and can get a bit more of the code to display, but not all of it.  Its just curious to say the least.

Comment: Interesting enough, I tried another stripped down version of the code and it could get it display the <% and %> tags no problem.  But anything HTML was rendered and things like included file links were not printed but were instead i believe executed.

Comment: If you are trying to display the file content on a web page you'll need to [HTML encode it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391148/692942) before displaying it so that HTML tags are not interpreted by the browser. If you are using ASP for your IDE then you should be able to encode the content using `encodedfilecontent = Server.HtmlEncode(thefilecontent)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reading and displaying a webservice output in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391148)

Comment: That makes some sense there, I double checked the ISAPI and only ASP Classic was there, so I will look into the encoding you mentioned and report back, thank you!

Comment: I am having some good results so far, its strange though as it is hit and miss.  Some HTML prints directly, others get ignored.  Some include files links are printed  Also the <style> tags and a few others are ignored, but your answer has helped me at least get some progress on this, so I appreciate it.   Is there anything to do like this for CSS or other parts, I am just encoding it line by line and so sometimes it seems to run fine, I will keep playing with it and if you have any other ideas please suggest.  Will update when final solution achieved and post update to question.

Comment: If you have a bunch of `Response.Write()` statements you will need to make sure they all include `Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode("thecontent"))` or you'll get a mixture. Another approach would be to build up a concatenated string then use `Response.Write()` once with `Server.HTMLEncode()` to output the encoded content.

Comment: Before each loop I have it encode the current line into a variable to display that instead, and it seems to be working as intended.  I seem to now have the full file displaying, and the only thing that gets left out is the first line and the last line, which is the html open and close tags, which I do not need anyways.   Thanks again!  Do you want to type something of an answer and I will mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to display HTML as text in a web browser you need to first HTML encode it or the web browser will interpret and render the HTML tags instead of simply displaying them as plain text.

You do this in Classic ASP by using the method

```
<%
Call Response.Write(Server.HTMLEncode(content))
%>
```

You will need to use `Server.HTMLEncode()` on any `Response.Write` method call that is returning the file content.

---

#### Useful Links

- [reading and displaying a webservice output in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391148) (Shows an example of HTML encoding in Classic ASP)

Comment: Is there a way to reverse the process?  Or is it impossible due to the order in which the server runs things?  I sort of want to maybe do a "preview" panel of the selected element, now that I can select the line and code from that line, I would maybe want to also display a "preview" of it rendering the HTML.  An example would be if they selected an <img> line of code, I have the ability to display the text, but could I also perhaps take that string of text and "run" it to display the image for example?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @easleyfixed Yes, but it requires a custom function as HTMLDecode is not included in Classic ASP. See [Classic ASP (VBScript) convert HTML codes to plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115708)

Comment: And ONE more thing if you don't mind, I am trying to use InSTR to compare when things are read on each line.  It seems like any of the lines that are HTML tags like <HEAD> or </Head> can't be detected properly I believe due to the < and > and maybe even / character for some reason.  I have tried using Chr(#) to encode specific characters and then use the & symbol to string them together, but no luck.  Maybe I am over looking something.  but an example is like:
IF InStr(THISLINE,"</div>") >= 1 THEN 
it doesn't seem to detect when I use < or / .. thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again for the first thing, it has worked wonders.  I don't know if you had time to look at the second question above, but I also have one more if you don't mind.  Is there a way to allow tabs into a form field to be read as a tab?  Likely has something to do with the encoding I am sure.   Probably need a javascript of sorts to capture the tab press or something?  This last one is the least critical, but very curious about it, thanks again.

Comment: Would it be better if i asked those as separate questions to get answers?  I think the first one I have worked a bit out of the Chr() codes but the second thing I believe might require reversing the html encoding like we talked about or somehow capturing the tab or enter key presses while inside of the text box.  Should I just ask that as a different question so its not strung off this post?

Comment: Think about it if you HTML encode the content you won’t be able to use `InStr()` to detected `<` or `>` you will need to use the encoded equivalent which is `&lt;` and `&gt;`. If you want to search something like a div tag use `&lt;div&gt;` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: Thank you, that is sort of what I was thinking, have to "manual" decode it, but its fine I printed off the Chr list, thanks again for your help!